# Compare two workbooks, copy entire rows of new data

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Credit for this code is for a few editors in Mr. Excel forum.

This code works, but I need it to copy the entire row of the new data, rather than only values from column A.

I tried to play with true and false statements and etc.

I have simple values, no formulas, just some named columns and thousands of rows in original file and extract file.

```vb
Sub AddMissingItems()
    Dim Dic As Object
    Dim Arr() As Variant, outArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim c as long
    
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        c = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
            If Dic.exists(Arr(i, 1)) = False Then
                Dic.Add (Arr(i, 1)), ""
            End If
        Next
    End With
    With Workbooks("ExtractFile").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(Arr), 1 To 1)
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            If Dic.exists(Arr(i, 1)) = False Then
                k = k + 1
                outArr(k, 1) = Arr(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    iRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row + 1
    If k <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Resize(k).Value = outArr
        k = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Tried adding Entirerow statement to several places, but to no avail.

Comment: What does "the entire row of the new data" mean? If this is only in you mind, I am afraid nobody can help you... If "your mission" will be clearly described you may also achieve what you need, I think.

Comment: Should that "new data" be defined as data not existing in `Workbooks("ExtractFile").Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A:A") and existing in `Sheets("Sheet1").range("A:A")` of the active workbook?

Comment: MM sorry, it basically means if a value from ExtractFile workbook column A is different from original source workbook column A value, as in new and not found in our source workbook it should take that value and put it into our source workbook from extract file workbook, but in this code that ive posted in takes only the column A value, where I actually need the whole row to be taken. Im sorry if its not as clear, even though my english is good I still find it difficult to explain this:P

Comment: Yes, it should be new data, not found in active workbook, but found in extract file

Comment: My issue is why I cannot complete my "mission" is that it only takes and paastes column A values, where as in if column A value new data is found in extract file I need that whole row taken to the active workbook

Comment: I would only assume something as := .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, would help, but I dont know how to implement it into the code

Comment: So, you need **the whole rows** where **data in A:A ("ExtractFile") sheet does not exist in A:A active sheet**. Would such an understanding be correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Couldnt have said it better myself

Comment: OK.  I will try adapting your code to deliver the whole row.

Comment: That would literally make my day as Ive been stuck on this for ages, started from simple copy/paste code and comparing, which worked, but guess what, data with huge rows tends to take hours without arrays and dictionary:) Happy because learnt VBA basics for excel, devasted because cant fully implement my mission.

Comment: Please, test the updated answer. it uses the basic logic of your existing code, extended to be able to return the whole necessary rows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. I commented where I input new variables/code lines:

```
Sub AddMissingItems()
    Dim Dic As Object, Arr() As Variant, outArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, iRow As Long, c As Long
    Dim r As Long, j As Long
    
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
            If Dic.Exists(Arr(i, 1)) = False Then
                Dic.Add (Arr(i, 1)), ""
            End If
        Next
    End With
    With Workbooks("ExtractFile.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        c = .cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
        r = .Range("A" & .rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'calculate the last row in A:A, too
        Arr = .Range("A1", .cells(r, c)).Value       'place in the array all existing columns
        ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(Arr), 1 To c) 'extend the redimmed array to all columns
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
            If Dic.Exists(Arr(i, 1)) = False Then
                k = k + 1
                For j = 1 To c 'iterate between all array columns:
                    outArr(k, j) = Arr(i, j) 'place the value from each column
                Next j
            End If
        Next
    End With
    iRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.count).End(3).row + 1
    If k <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Resize(k, UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = outArr 'resize by  columns, too
        k = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: For the line Next k (it is located near the end of code) I get the following error: Compile error: Invalid Next control variable reference

Comment: @Rokas Ups... It should be `Next j`... I will update the code. Updated.

Comment: now the line : outArr(k, j) = Arr(i, j) 'place the value from each column, has the following error: Subscript out of range

Comment: Would It help if id provide example excel files with small amount of these rows?

Comment: @Rokas Yes, I will have something to test the code. The above one is not tested... You may use a transfer site. [this one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: easyupload.io/m/o82145

Comment: In the extract File there is a new row, basically that should be transfered to the source workbook, without copying the ones that already are stored in source workbook

Comment: @Rokas No problem. I will adapt the code in maximum 2 - 3 minutes...

Comment: @Rokas Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Sir, it works perfect and you just made my evening! Thank you so much! I will try to understand the code and most definitely sending you all the positive energy I can FaneDuru! Thank you!

Comment: @Rokas Not so difficult to be understand. Now, `Arr` (the second one) contains all the workbook columns, not only one as initially and `outArr` has been redimentioned to keep all of them, too (`ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(Arr), 1 To c)`). Then, instead of taking only the unique first column value, it takes all columns value by iteration, using `j` variable for that...

Comment: I see now, it is truly fascinating what arrays and dictionaries can achieve, as Ive had a code that done the same but using the clipboard directly, and while it works for small amount of data it really does not do a good job with thousands of rows, which make the code work for hours or perhaps more. Im glad this brought me to VBA and I think It will make any excel work for me way more efficient. Have a good evening @FaneDuru and once again thank you!

Comment: I see that you used one Array `Arr` twice, is this means no need to use `Erase Arr` ?

Comment: @Waleed Nope... `ReDim` set new array dimensions but also **clears the array**. `ReDim Preserve` **keeps the array content***, but allows only changing of the **last dimension**.

Comment: I mean, you earlier set `Arr = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .rows.count).End(xlUp).row).Value` and later you set `Arr = .Range("A1", .cells(r, c)).Value`

Comment: @Waleed When doing that you can reuse the same array **whenever you want**. Of course, if you do not need the previous loaded data. In the above code, it has been necessary only to load the dictionary. You need to erase and `ReDim`, only if you intend/need to load the array **element by element**. When you need to use `arr(1, 2) = x`. When load it from a range, as in the above example, no any such a need.